Configure latency parameters for CPU cache hit/miss latency in Gem5
I'm configuring the hit latency for a CPU model in Gem5. While I notice there are many latency parameters(eg. tag_latency, data_latency, frontend_latency, forward_latency, response_latency) which are quite similar to hit latency. How could I know the clear defination for these parameters and how to configure their values?
Any discussion would be helpful! Thanks a lot!
I check a website which gives me some inspire but not enough, here is the link:
https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~swilson/gem5-docs/classBaseXBar.html

The BaseCache::calculateAccessLatency() function in cache/base.cc can explain this question very well.
If tag and data are accessed sequential, the hit_latency = tag_latency + data_latency + header_delay, on the other hand, the hit_latency = header_delay + max(tag_latency, data_datency). The header_delay can be set to zero here.
Both frontend_latency and forward_latency is used to simulate the request latency, response_latency is used to simulate the response latency, all of them are configured in Xbar.py, for simulating the bus/xbar transmit latency.
